# Flux TypeError: Class constructor AccessManagement cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs-flux

I installed React Flux. I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor AccessManagement cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

---

What needs to be instanciated? This is my class.

```
class Reports extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      static getStores() {
        return [ReportsStore];
      }

      static calculateState(prevState, props) {
        const rep = ReportsStore.getState();

        return {
          isLoading: rep.isLoading,
          reportRequests: rep.ReportRequests
        };
      }
      render() {

        return (<dvi></div>
        );
      }

      componentDidMount() {
      }
    }

    export default Container.create(Reports);
```

The flux version is: `"flux": "^3.1.3"`,
Any idea how to solve this?